# Copy music from Ipod to Ubuntu

Tags: music, ipod, transfer

can anyone please help me for this ? in fact i can see the musics in the ipod but they all are like "HHDW.mp3" "KZDE.mp3" FPPD.mp3" ... and i just can't rename every single song by listening to it ...
Do anyone have a solution for that ?
Thanks

Comment: Since gtkpod only works with certain hardware and versions of iOS, The title of this question should reflect that as this answer will not work for more than half current idevice users. Please write the device name and iOS version, so people with other versions can find fixes to their issues as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [gtkpod Ipod manager](http://www.gtkpod.org/wiki/Home) which is available from the software center.

Comment: Ah yeah it works. It bugged at first that's why i asked the question, but now it works. Thank you.

Comment: it actually still bug a little ...

Comment: Can't help you with that,im not the developer nor i have used the application before since i do not own an ipod.You can also use Hipo iPod Management Tool which is also available at the software center.

Comment: yeah i know, it was just a kind of "ps". Thx again